# Is there a way to unzip archive without crushing owner?

Tags: zip

I'm actually working on a Windows OS for development purposes. I  have some  config files which i want to deploy on a linux based system. The structure of the zip generated on Windows is the same as the target.

When i unzip my archive in the linux system, the unzip command change the owner of original files with the user who make the unzip (root).

Before unzip :

```
[root@supermachine /]# ll /myRootFolder -R
/myRootFolder:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 superman superman  5 21 août  10:18 file.TXT
drwxr-xr-x 2 superman superman 25 21 août  10:17 mySubFolder

/myRootFolder/mySubFolder:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 superman superman 4 21 août  10:17 subFile.TXT
```

After unzip

```
[root@supermachine /]# unzip myRootFolder.zip
Archive:  myRootFolder.zip
replace myRootFolder/file.TXT? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
 extracting: myRootFolder/file.TXT
replace myRootFolder/mySubFolder/subFile.TXT? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: y
 extracting: myRootFolder/mySubFolder/subFile.TXT

[root@supermachine /]# ll /myRootFolder -R
/myRootFolder:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      5 21 août  10:18 file.TXT
drwxr-xr-x 2 superman superman 25 21 août  10:21 mySubFolder

/myRootFolder/mySubFolder:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 21 août  10:17 subFile.TXT
```

For information, unzip version is :

```
[root@supermachine /]$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/ ;
see ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-26) for Unix (Linux ELF) on Jan 10 2018.

UnZip special compilation options:
        COPYRIGHT_CLEAN (PKZIP 0.9x unreducing method not supported)
        SET_DIR_ATTRIB
        SYMLINKS (symbolic links supported, if RTL and file system permit)
        TIMESTAMP
        UNIXBACKUP
        USE_EF_UT_TIME
        USE_UNSHRINK (PKZIP/Zip 1.x unshrinking method supported)
        USE_DEFLATE64 (PKZIP 4.x Deflate64(tm) supported)
        UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars, char coding: UTF-8] (handle UTF-8 paths)
        MBCS-support (multibyte character support, MB_CUR_MAX = 6)
        LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT (large files over 2 GiB supported)
        ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
        USE_BZIP2 (PKZIP 4.6+, using bzip2 lib version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010)
        VMS_TEXT_CONV
        [decryption, version 2.11 of 05 Jan 2007]

UnZip and ZipInfo environment options:
           UNZIP:  [none]
        UNZIPOPT:  [none]
         ZIPINFO:  [none]
      ZIPINFOOPT:  [none]
```

Is there an option on zip command to preserve original owner of crushed files ? I read the manual but i see anything related to these case.

***Note :*** If there is a solution with other kind of archive, it can also resolve my issue (i can generate other archive formats).

Comment: How should a filesystem like EXT4 for example deal with NTFS permissions in this case? This won't work because of the differences between Linux and Windows.

Comment: I don't think that zip stores ownership details. If there is only one owner, then you can change owner before unzipping.

Comment: Top tip: If you can stop using Microsoft's Windows. If you can't then set up a Gnu/Linux in virtual box.

Comment: tar will preserve ownership

Comment: Which version of unzip are you using?  Please include the output of `unzip --version`.  (I think the answer will still be "no, there's no such option", but can only be sure by systematically going through every option supported by that exact version.)

Comment: @JigglyNaga, i add my unzip version to my answer. Thanks for your attention on my issue.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the su command to run the unzip as the user that you want to own the files:

```
su -c "unzip myRootFolder.zip" superman
```

---

su allows you to run a command as another user, or temporarily become that user within the current login session. Run

```
man su
```

for a complete description of the command.

Answer (score 0):

`unzip` does not have a function to do precisely what you're describing.

When it asked you

```
replace myRootFolder/file.TXT? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:
```

and you responded `y`, "replace" meant that it deleted the original file before extracting the new copy.  The original file is gone, including all its metadata (owner, permissions, timestamps).

## Using backup files

An option that does part of what you need would be the `-B` option, to keep a backup of all overwritten files.  After `unzip -B`, you should see (in the `ll` / `ls` output) that as well as the update file, there's the original file with a `~` at the end of its name:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 superman superman  5 21 août  10:18 file.TXT~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      5 21 août  10:18 file.TXT
```

From there, you need to copy each backup file's ownership to the new file with `chown`, then remove the backup files afterwards.

You could do this with eg. `find -exec`:

```
find myRootFolder -name "*~" -exec bash -c 'bak="{}";
  new="${bak%\~}";
  chown --reference "$bak" "$new" ; rm "$bak"' \;
```

but this will cause problems if you already had filenames ending with `~`, before any backups were created.

Alternatively, you could list the zip contents (using the `zipinfo` command included with Info-ZIP), and for each one, check whether a backup even exists before doing the `chown`...`rm`.

```
zipinfo -1 myRootFolder.zip | grep -v '$/' | while read new ; do
  bak="${new}~"
  test -e "$bak" || continue
  chown --reference "$bak" "$new"
  rm "$bak"
done
```

Comment: This is going to give bad results if some of the files (on the file system, or in the zip) already have a "~" at the end.  There are probably other edge cases I've missed, too.

Comment: Thanks for our response @JigglyNaga. I think your solution is very close to what I want. We can execute a script shell after unziping to make chown command only on files which have a backup in the same directory. A cleaner solution is also with a shell script which list files in the zip archive and make the chown command only on files extracted from this archive.

Comment: @FlorianG Edited to add a script that does exactly that.